# Fixed pitch(width) fonts only in QFontDialog

Tags: qt, fonts, dialog, width, fixed

I wander how to make QFontDialog to display only those fonts with a certain characteristics (in my case, it is a fixed pitch that I need). It is surprisingly, Qt documentation tells nothing about such an obvious feature.

Comment: Is the [`QFontDialog::MonospacedFonts`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdialog.html#FontDialogOption-enum) option what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's true for Qt5. But unfortunately, I am stuck with Qt4 (4.8.7), which is missing it. Any idea for Qt4?